# rewrite rule: regular expression to remove variable from link

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got urls like this one:

**my-party/viewparty/243-party-in-berlin-2013.html**

where the variable part of the url is:

**243-party-in-berlin-2013.html**

I neet to get a url like:

**events/party-in-berlin-2013.html**

how can I do it with the apache rewrite rule? I've managed to remove the "my-party/viewparty" but I can't remove the portion of variable link.
Thank you very much

Alessandro

Comment: the question is not quite clear. do you want just to remove 243- prefix or fully replace last path element of url (what-ever-party.html) with party-in-berlin-2013.html?

Comment: hello, I need to replace my-party/viewparty/243-party-in-berlin-2013.html url with events/party-in-berlin-2013.html where 243- portion of the url is variable

Answer (score 1):

The following will map any URI in the format:

`my-party/viewparty/<digits>-<rest-of-file-name>.html`

to

`/events/<rest-of-file-name>.html`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} my-party/viewparty/\d+-([^\.]*\.html)$
RewriteRule .* /events/%1 [L]
```

The way it works, is that it captures (what's inside the parentheses) the last part (denoted by the dollar-sign) of the request uri, that ends with `.html` and is preceded by `my-party/viewparty/\d+-`, where `\d+` denotes a string of digits, with a minimum length of one digit. It then appends this captured pattern (denoted by `%1`) to `/events/` in the `RewriteRule`.

If you want to redirect ([301 Moved Permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#301)) to the new URI, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} my-party/viewparty/\d+-([^\.]*\.html)$
RewriteRule .* /events/%1 [R=301,L]
```

And, if the `party-in-berlin-2013` part is not variable, then you could can simply replace the `RewriteCond` with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} my-party/viewparty/\d+-(party-in-berlin-2013\.html)$
```